# complete SDL 1.2 documentation?

Tags: sdl, sdl-1.2

I've been trying to find complete documentation for SDL 1.2. I can't use SDL 2 for several reasons which I don't want to go over right now, but basically, I can't find any wiki backups for SDL 1.2 other than a [rather incomplete snapshot on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20041215060515/http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FrontPage), [this tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/), and the [man pages](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsdl1.2-dev), and none of which contain information on how to use `SDL_RWops`.

So, I guess I need one of two things, a man page or simple outline of `SDL_RWops` and its associated functions, or, preferably, a *complete* backup of the wiki pre-2.0. I'm sure *somewhere* there's a backup of the wiki, but I just haven't found it.

Comment: [`SDL_rwops.h`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/blob/release-1.2.15/include/SDL_rwops.h) has some light documentation.  There's also [`testfile.c`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/blob/release-1.2.15/test/testfile.c) but it doesn't do anything terribly interesting.

Comment: RWops API haven't changed with SDL2, except offset argument type. You can use current wiki, it even mentions that change.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20041214085331/http://sdldoc.csn.ul.ie/) is an archive of the old API wiki.

As for `SDL_RWops` it's something like:

```
SDL_RWops rw;
rw = SDL_RWFromFile("/path/to/filename", "rb"); // rb being mode
```

It seems to retain the same signature in [SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RWFromFile).